# Possible to translate jquery into javascript to set classnames on items in an OnClicked() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, translate

I'm a total nub but is there any way to rewrite the following piece of jquery code into javascript so it nolonger needs the jquery library to function?

```
function LoadSnippet(id, value)
{
    $('#js-content').load(value);

    // deselect all
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("lookClickable");

    for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) 
    {
        items[i].className="notclicked tablip lookClickable";
    }

    // select one
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.className ="clicked tablip lookClickable";
}
```

Comment: What even is that doing? Are the `.lookClickable` classes in the new html? If so, then you should be using the callback

Comment: jQuery code **is** JavaScript. It's not a separate language, it's just a library.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, and the correct answer to his question would technically just be a "Yes", but most people can read between the lines.

Comment: There are elements in the same html that I want to change the class names of. Basically one element is clicked and I make it look selected while the rest get greyed out. The load gets a piece of html code dependant on which element was clicked.

Comment: @SourceOverflow unfortunately in the 8 years I've been on this site I guess I just haven't figured that stuff out.

Comment: Pointy -- I was almost that far. Nevertheless if I don't include the jquery link it will not work, so I need to rewrite to be able to leave this out, right?

Comment: If you are binding with `load()` you shouldn't do that, as it has been deprecated. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `fetch` then save use `document.querySelector` to select the div you want to save the html to like this:

```
async function LoadSnippet(id, value)
{
    let response = await fetch(value);
    document.querySelector('#js-content').innerHTML = await response.text()

    // The rest of your code:
    // deselect all
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("lookClickable");

    for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) 
    {
        items[i].className="notclicked tablip lookClickable";
    }

    // select one
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.className ="clicked tablip lookClickable";
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
    LoadSnippet(1, '/path/to/my/page.html') 
})
```

Comment: No need to await the promise twice. Also you might want to use `.then` instead of waiting to make it really async.

Comment: `fetch()` returns a promise, so does `text()`, so yes you do need to `await` twice

Comment: This looks great, thanks GetOffMyLawn. I just realize I'll have to make an initial call from something like  $(document).ready(function(). Is there an equivalent in Javascript for that as well?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Oh right, I'm sorry, didn't expect that. Prob. should have done some more research first.

Comment: I have updated the code with with a `$(document).ready()` replacement

Comment: You're Welcome! Accept the answer so you can earn reputation.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn seems like OP didn't took a [tour]